# What's wrong with this UPDATE FROM using a case statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

```
update p
set p.storePrice = 
    CASE 
       WHEN p.costPrice BETWEEN 0.00 AND 1.00 
       THEN p.costPrice * 1.0
    CASE 
       WHEN p.costPrice BETWEEN 0.00 AND 1.00 
       THEN p.costPrice * 1.0
    ELSE 
       p.msrpPrice
    END
FROM product p                      
WHERE p.type = 1
```

The error says:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
```

**I can't seem to see any issue with the sql?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two starting `case`'s.  Remove the second one, like:

```
case 
    when x=1 then ...
    when x=2 then ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
UPDATE p
    SET 
     p.storePrice = 
            CASE 
                WHEN 
                    p.costPrice BETWEEN 0.00 AND 1.00 
                    THEN p.costPrice * 1.0

                WHEN 
                    p.costPrice BETWEEN 0.00 AND 1.00 
                    THEN p.costPrice * 1.0                              

                ELSE 
                    p.msrpPrice
            END
FROM product p                    
WHERE p.type = 1
```